# Observable и Subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, observer

Всем привет, пытаюсь разобраться с подписками Observable.
У меня есть такой код.

Суть в том, что у меня есть карточка персонажа с информацией о нем. Если я кликаю, например, на его возможности, то у меня открывается модальное окно с чекбоксами, где я могу выбрать возможности. после выбора чекбокса и клика на кнопку "сохранить", я предполагала, что информация в карточке обновится, благодаря подписке, но это происходит только в момент, когда я руками обновляю страницу, что не совсем верно

```
   subscribe$: Subscription;

   randomFunction() {
    //body

    let observable$: Observable<boolean[]>;
    
    <Здесь переменной observable$ присваиваются значения по условиям>
    
    this.subscribe$ = observable$.subscribe(
    () => {
    this.service.refresh('myData');
    });
}
```

Я предполагала, что данный код позволит мне обновлять данные и сразу отображать изменения, но в моем случае это не работает. Я не могу понять где допустила ошибку в коде. Если кто-то может помочь разобраться с Observable и подписками, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: так тут нет кода обновления. Да и observable пустой и не проинициализированный

Comment: @Grundy все обновление происходит в вызове refresh и там все отрабатывает верно, потому что в других местах. где я ее использую, все хорошо. А что вы имеете ввиду по поводу observable? Мне нужно присвоить ему значение, когда объявляю?

Comment: в таком виде `let observable$: Observable<boolean[]>;
    this.subscribe$ = observable$.subscribe(` - в консоли должна быть ошибка, о том, что идет попытка вызвать метод у `undefined`. Скорее всего даже сборка не должна пройти

Comment: @Grundy извините, я не совсем верно написала код для примера, там идет присваивание значение, а после this.subscribe$ = observable$.subscribe()

Comment: сделай [mcve] на какой-либо из площадок, чтобы можно было запустить и увидеть ошибку. На первый взгляд должно все работаеть

Comment: @Grundy честно говоря, у меня не получается объединить информацию с нескольких страниц в один код.. Может я могу дать более подробное описание, как это должно работать?...

Comment: Просто консоль все равно не выдает никаких ошибок. Просто если я ставлю чекбокс, например, в модальном окне, обновленная информация в карточке появится только после обновления страницы, а не сразу после клика на сохранить.

Comment: По описанию нельзя сказать как это внутри работает ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Что ты имеешь ввиду под "модальным окном", что происходит по клику сохранить? Для этого и нужен минимальный пример, демонстрирующий ошибку.

Comment: @Grundy https://wdfiles.ru/6ea80c

Comment: используй https://codesandbox.io/ или https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @Grundy https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-moon-qky53s?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: В песочнице, если отметить чекбокс в попапе - при закрытии отмечаются и основные. Выглядит, будто работает так как ты ожидаешь?